# I can not find out the way to create “secret word” on the “Merchant tools” page on moneybookers

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I want to integrate moneybookers api in my web site.

I have created an account on moneybookers.

To integrate moneybookers API, i need secret word under Merchant tools.

But where is  “Merchant tools”  and where is “secret word”?

I have attached two  screenshots of member panel on moneybookers.

This is in my account-
[image]

But from the tutorial-
http://wyday.com/blog/2011/automate-moneybookers-skrill-using-status_url-ipn-php-asp-net/
The  screenshots to Create a “secret word” is-
[image]

Comment: Have you read the [manual](https://www.moneybookers.com/merchant/de/automated_payments_interface_manual.pdf) or [contacted moneybookers](https://www.moneybookers.com/app/help.pl?s=contact)?

Comment: i have read and created an  “Business account”. But i cannot understand what to do after this to get secret word.

Comment: I noticed their FAQ section is quite sparse, but they might have technical support, which I imagine would be of more use to you.

Comment: I'ts fun to see that such a question is on SO. I still haven't found the way to generate the `secret word`

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to contact `merchantservices@moneybookers.com` and ask for the things you cannot find. That's what they also write in their manuals.

> ... please contact your account manager or merchantservices@moneybookers.com.

Comment: This email is inactive

Comment: Thanks for the update. This is what I found in 2012 in their manual. I'm not checking every month if the email address is still correct. The answer helps as a hint to know where to look for.

Answer (score 0):

The site [Moneybookers](http://www.moneybooker.com/) is now known as [Skrill](https://www.skrill.com/en/) (bear that in mind as some of the following information might be confusing elsewise)

> Skrill (formerly Moneybookers) [...]

*Taken from [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skrill).*

---

Anyhow, you want to access the **Merchant tools** of Moneybookers/Skrill. To achieve this you need to update your Skrill account to a business account (often referred to as [*"Moneybookers merchant account"*](https://www.paymentwall.com/en/documentation/Instructions-for-Moneybookers/1257)), otherwise you're **not** able to **a.)** access the tab "Merchant Tools" and **b.)** therefore set a secret word (which will be available on the "Merchant Tools" tab.

[image: Overview of the Merchant tools]
*Screenshot taken from [this source](https://www.conftool.net/en/configuration_documentation/skrill_moneybookers_configuration.html)*

---

To create a Moneybookers merchant account, please check the two following links for **further reading** purposes:

- Check out [this tutorial by ConfTool](https://www.conftool.net/en/configuration_documentation/skrill_moneybookers_configuration.html); **only Step 1 and 2** matter as Step 3 is specifically for ConfTool Pro and thus not relevant for you.
- Analog to the last tutorial, just [look at the Moneybookers related part](https://www.paymentwall.com/en/documentation/Instructions-for-Moneybookers/1257).

*If you have any problems with the process, I highly suggest you to look for Skrill related tutorials as "Moneybookers" returns old (most often outdated material).*

Comment: @User Let me know if there are any questions left regarding my answer!